# Type aliases/abbreviations can't access members?

Tags: types, f#, aliases

F# type aliases are not working as I would expect.  e.g.

```
type MyMap = Map<string, string>

let myMap = ["One", "1"; "Two", "2"] |> Map.ofList
let myMap2= ["One", "1"; "Two", "2"] |> MyMap.ofList
```

The first let works fine. The second one fails with:

> error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'ofList' is not
>   defined

Which mystifies me.  I would have expected that if MyMap is an alias for Map, all the members of Map would be accessible through MyMap.

Is there some doc somewhere that explains this?

At [F# for Fun and Profit: Type abbreviations](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/type-abbreviations/) it says that the compiler will actually replace the abbreviation with the actual underlying type.  I had assumed that would include member references.

Comment: The `Map.ofList` function is in the `Map` **module**, not the `Map` **type**. Try "module MyMapMod = Map` and you should be able to access `MyMapMod.ofList`. (A silly example that gains you nothing in this particular case since `Map` is a lot shorter, but it's just for example purposes).

Comment: Aha!  I see the distinction. Good to know.  Thanks!